# Updating A Program's Directory

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a program that uses forms.  The forms are pointing to files in c:\filepath1 as set forth in main.prg (set defa, set path).   I make a test copy of the files, change the path in main.prg, the forms are still referencing the files in the old path.  I don't want to have to recreate all the data environments in all the forms.  How can I avoid doing so?  Any help on this would be kindly appreciated.

Missy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Dataenvironment is used AND the path recorded in DataEnvironment tables exist, then that path is used no matter what the current path is. If you don't want to touch Dataenvironment at all (even programmatically) then you must remove that path (rename for example).

As a side note: I have:

```
UpdateDE(this)
```

in my DataEnvironment.BeforeOpenTables method. In UpdateDE.prg I have code that loops all the cursors in DE and set their path to the one that I want to use as "current".

EDIT: Here is a sample UpdateDE.prg:

```
Lparameters toDE
Do setups && prg keeping common "set" entries
Local Array aDEMembers[1]
Local lnMembers,ix,lcMembers
If !(Type('oApp')='O' And !Isnull(m.oApp))
  Public oApp
  oApp = Createobject('myApp')
Endif
lnMembers = Amembers(aDEMembers,m.toDE,2)
For ix=1 To m.lnMembers
  With Evaluate('toDe.'+aDEMembers[m.ix])
    If Lower(.BaseClass) == 'cursor'
      If Atc(oApp.cAppDBC,.Database) > 0
        .Database = Addbs(oApp.cAppDataPath)+oApp.cAppDBC
      Else
        .CursorSource = Addbs(oApp.cAppDataPath)+Justfname(.CursorSource)
      Endif
    Endif
  Endwith
Endfor

Define Class myApp As Custom
  cAppDBC = 'myDatabase.dbc'
  cAppDataPath=Fullpath('data')
  cCurPath = ''
  Procedure Init
    This.cCurPath = Set('path')
    If File('dbparam.dbf') && a small dbf that holds path to current data folder
      Select dataLoc From dbparam Where locType == 'DATABASE' Into Array arrDataLoc
      If _Tally > 0
        This.cAppDataPath = arrDataLoc
        Set Path To (arrDataLoc[1]+';'+This.cCurPath)
      Endif
      Use In 'dbparam'
    Endif
  Endproc
  Procedure Destroy
    Set Path To (This.cCurPath)
  Endproc
Enddefine
```

Comment: Cetin -- you sure love the Fox :)

Comment: Although I work with other languages too, yes I do :) BTW I add such things to all forms programmatically. If you need it inform me.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up renaming the default path then going through all the screens in the program then recompiling.  Thank you for your help.  I did understand it and is probably another good solution.